# Selenium error: The Selenium Server is not active on host localhost at port 4444

Tags: testing, selenium, phpunit

testing the following object with (phpunit and selenium installed):

```
 <?php

class TestLogin extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase{

public function setUp()
{
    $this->setHost('localhost');
    $this->setPort(4444);
    $this->setBrowser('firefox');
    $this->setBrowserUrl('http://debian-vm/phpUnitTutorial');
}


public function testHasLoginForm()
{
    $this->url('');

    $email = $this->byName('email');
    $password = $this->byName('password');

    $this->assertEquals('', $email->value());
    $this->assertEquals('', $password->value());
}
}
```

This throws the following error:

```
Time: 9 ms, Memory: 6.75Mb

There was 1 skipped test:

1) testLogin::testHasLoginForm
The Selenium Server is not active on host localhost at port 4444.

OK, but incomplete, skipped, or risky tests!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Skipped: 1.
```

Is there a way to fix this? I followed a tutorial through youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zva_GETXimI#t=12 And I got stuck almost at the beginning.

Comment: Did you start the Selenium server?

Comment: If you navigate to http://localhost:4444/wd/hub ?

Comment: Thanks guys! I did not realize selenium connection server should be running at the same time. Now I get another message error but I try to solve it. If you gontrollez added an answer regarding this matter I would give you props otherwise I will do it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that the selenium server is running in your host.

Comment: How do you check that ?